# Tiempo determinado en una pagina especifica

Tags: php, laravel

Buen día me encuentro realizando un aula virtual para una empresa en laravel. Me pide que para rendir un examen el alumno ingrese en el examen y allí permanezca un tiempo determinado para rendirla y que sólo pueda ingresar 1 sola vez. No se me ocurre la verdad como programar esa parte. 
  Es decir que el alumno ingrese a "rendir evaluación" y permanezca una sesión iniciada hasta que termine de rendir todas las preguntas sin que pueda refrescar la pagina ni nada parecido. Que solo permanezca allí dentro hasta que termine de rendir o se le acabe el tiempo. 
  Agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

En php puedes establecer una variable de sesión con el timestamp del momento en el que solicita la página.

Después simplemente tienes que ir controlando cuanto tiempo ha transcurrido desde ese momento, puedes hacerlo con peticiones ajax cada 1 min o lo que necesites. Si se ha superado el tiempo permitido rediriges al usuario... ¿a su casa?

Si se vuelve a recargar, en la parte de PHP controlas si existe ya o no esa variable en la sesión del usuario y no permitir que se entregue el "examen" si ya existía previamente.

Tienes bastantes opciones jugando con las variables de sesión.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Dale Jonathan me abriste bastante la cabeza con eso de la sesion y tiempos. Vamos a ir probando como se comportan las variables de sesion con su tiempo correspondiente. Muchas gracias